# Can we pass extra arguments to ANTD form.submit event?

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

Here is some code about antd form, where I am calling handleFinish inside onFinish prop and on button click, calling form.submit function as we do normally to trigger the handleFinish function of form outside the form. Only difference here we have is, that I am passing some extra arguments to form.submit that my handleFinish function is expecting but all the variables are undefined.

```
<Form
   onFinish={(value, isNext, isApprove, isDownload) => {
      handleFinish(value, isNext, isApprove, isDownload);
   }}
   form={form}
>
...
</Form>

// This button cannot go inside form due to some reason
<Button onClick={() => form.submit(form.getFieldsValue(), false, true, false))}>Submit</Button>
```

I have tried passing the arguments and tried to get them inside onFinish but that is undefined, then I also tried passing form.getFieldsValue() which is not necessary by the way but just to give a try that may be arguments position is disturbing somehow but still won't work.
One solution that I have in my mind is to store all these arguments inside some state and update the states on click and then use the state variables inside the handleFinish function. But that is something I do not want to do as it seems not a good solution.

Also, when we tried debugging and going into the onFinish of antd form inside the node_modules, here is the code that we found,

```
onFinish: function onFinish(values) {
   formContext.triggerFormFinish(name, values);
   if (_onFinish) {
      _onFinish(values);
   }
}
```

So, it seems like the onFinish of antd form is ignoring all the extra arguments because it accepts only one argument which is values.

I am expecting the form.submit has to accept parameters and those parameters has to be accessible inside handleFinish function.

Really appreciate your answers or comments on it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't pass extra arguments to `form.submit()`.

`onFinish` event only returns the current form values so one sollution is to set your other params inside the form with `form.setFieldValue` or `form.setFieldsValue` to set multiple values at once and these values will be available in `onFinish` event:

Here's an example of how you can use it:

```
<Button onClick={() => {
  form.setFieldsValue({
    isNext: false,
    is.....
  })
  form.submit()
}}>Submit</Button>

...

onFinish={({
  isNext, isApprove, isDownload, ...rest
}) => {
  handleFinish(rest, isNext, isApprove, isDownload);
}}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That's seems like a good solution. Thanks man!